# Why are first requests to my website slow

Tags: performance, http, request, connection

I have 2 websites hosted on the same Widows server 2012 on the same IIS 8.5. Website1 is asp.net classic hosted in managed mode while [website2](https://topiqs.online/) is asp.net core 2.2 hosted in no-managed mode with IIS as an reverse proxy (default asp.net core hosting) using the InProcess hosting model.

Then requesting website1 from a browser, website1 is fast to connect.
Then requesting website2 from a browser, website2 is slow to connect on first request.

I don't think it is a cache problem on the server, because while subsequent requests connects fast in the same browser, if I open say Chrome in inkognito mode, the first request in that browser will be slow to connect even if I have just connected using standard Chrome (or Firefox).

So could it be a connection cache problem?, well both website 1 and random websites are generally always fast to connect on first requests (only website2 is slow to connect). The time I have to wait in the browser after I have made a request until the next request will become slow again is highly inconsistent, it can be 30 seconds to many minutes.

What possible reasons can there be for slow connection on the first request that fits the above observations ?

Here is a picture that shows the first request connection from Chrome DevTools Networks tab.
[image]

Here is another example there the "Initial connection" is 21 seconds but the "Stalled" is 0 seconds.
[image]

Comment: Have you tried from a different client/environment? The delay is in "Stalled" phase, which means your browser hasn't been able to send the first packet out. Which means in case of no client side proxy, it could not send out the SYN for 18s. A local AV, IPS, browser extension etc could be involved.Or in case of client side proxy, it took 18 seconds to get a response back from proxy server (before it could start SSL handshake).

Comment: Good place to start: https://developers.google.com/web/tools/chrome-devtools/network/understanding-resource-timing

Comment: I have added an image showing that the long connection start does not necessarily happen because the request is stalled. Also I have confirmed that the first request takes a long time to connect from 2 different countries (Denmark & Thailand). However, based on singhatulks first comment, I will test more how the first request perform in other browsers AND also I have a Chrome extension related to the problem website (though disabling the extension did not change anything).